# Error trying to extract data from PDFs in Solr 8

Tags: solr, apache-tika

Using Solr 8 Data Import Handler and Tika, I am trying to combine data from a MySQL database (paper title, conference presented at, etc) together with content extracted from the respective PDFs. When I send a query such as `http://localhost:8983/solr/proceedings/select?hl=on&q=*:*` I get the expected type and number of results. The fields from the db query itself are all being returned, no problem, but it does not seem as if any of the content from the PDFs is getting indexed.

When I run a query like `http://localhost:8983/solr/proceedings/select?hl=on&q=content:*Kiowa*` or `http://localhost:8983/solr/proceedings/select?hl=on&q=text:*Kiowa*` I do not get any errors, but neither do I get any results. Just 0 documents found, even though there are PDFs containing the word "Kiowa."

"Text" and "content" are in my schema as:

```
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

Here is my data-config.xml:

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
    driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    name="proceedings_db"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB?useSSL=false"
    user="myUser" 
    password="myPassword" />

    <dataSource name="proceedings_files" type="BinFileDataSource" />

<document>
    <entity name="proceedingsContent" dataSource="proceedings_db" onerror="skip"
        query="SELECT productID, title, downLoadableFile, fileName AS paper_file FROM proceedings WHERE status = '1' AND downLoadableFile LIKE '%pdf'
    ">
        <field column="productID" name="id" />
        <field column="title" name="paper_title" />
        <field column="downLoadableFile" name="downLoadableFile" />
        <field column="paper_file" name="paper_file" />
        
        <entity name="files" dataSource="null" rootEntity="false" processor="FileListEntityProcessor" baseDir="c:/proceedings" fileName="${proceedingsContent.downLoadableFile}" onError="skip" recursive="true">

            <entity name="documentImport" dataSource="proceedings_files" processor="TikaEntityProcessor" url="${files.fileAbsolutePath}" format="text" onerror="skip">
                <field column="text" name="text" />
            </entity>
        
        </entity>

    </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

I would appreciate any assistance. Many thanks in advance!